# Sending variable from Adapter to Activity

Tags: java, android

In my app I use a `CardView`. When a card is clicked, another activity opens which needs the id of the card. So I tried to send the data through the intent which I'm using to open the activity as well.
My problem is that the received value in the receiving class always stays `0`, although the shared value is different. Am I getting it wrong?

The part of the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final int a = dataAdapter.getId();

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CardID", a);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

The second class that gets the value:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int cardId = intent.getIntExtra("cardID", 0);
        Log.d("cardId = ", String.valueOf(cardId)); 
}
```

Comment: Check answer, Its a char mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When u are inserting, CardID "C" is uppercase while when u are getting it cardID "c" is lowecase.It is case sensitive just make them both the same case and that should work.

Comment: @user9155899 :: for this very reason I always declare constants for my "Extra keys" :: `static final String EXTRA_CARD_ID =  "ExtraCardId"; ` then just use that in your code :: `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CARD_ID , a);`

Answer (score 2):

Replace with this -

`intent.getIntExtra("CardID", 0);`

Capital C is missing.

Answer (score -1):

If your dataAdapter is a list, you can use **position** param in `onBindViewHolder()`.

```
intent.putExtra("CardID", dataAdapter.get(position));
```

or you can use `getAdapterPosition()` only if you use **recyclerViewAdapter**

```
intent.putExtra("CardID", dataAdapter.get(getAdapterPosition()));
```